# What to put in -v using Aspnet_Compiler

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows-server-2012, aspnet-compiler

I have an in-place website in .NET running on Windows Server 2012. I would like to try pre-compiling it to speed up the first page response. The site is running on a second virtual website in IIS.

Calling the site on the local machine it runs at `http://localhost:88/AppVersion/AppSite/`

The documentation for `aspnet_compile` when in place says the -v key is the one I want. I just can't work out what path to use for the -v option when you are on a virtual site. Have tried putting full path; partial path and just get invalid path errors from aspnet_compile.

What I can't work out is the something: in `aspnet_compile -v {something}`

Answer (score 0):

`-v` is the virtual path. Put the path to your application from the hosting root. I *think* that by your example, you'd put in: `-v /AppVersion/Appsite/` I haven't tried it with a site NOT on its own domain.

Here's what I use for a site on its own domain:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler -v / -p C:\Projects\branches\demo3\KenticoCMS -fixednames C:\Projects\branches\demo3precomp
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/ms229863(v=vs.80)